# How to create a database programmatically in Sqlite using C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sqlite, mfc

I am using Visual Studio.
Using VC++/MFC and SQLite, how would I programmatically create a database?

Comment: Just open it; the database file will be created automatically when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Sqlite wrapper for C++.

You can find some here: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers

One example is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a wrapper for doing that. You can simply use the `sqlite3_open_v2` function with the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flag:

```
sqlite3* pDb = NULL;
int rc = sqlite3_open_v2("yourDbName.db", &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
assert(rc == SQLITE_OK);
```